# Django Celery Beat - Runaway Process on Ubuntu

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have celerybeat running as a service on ubuntu.

[image]

Generally speaking, everything works great. I have the same setup on numerous servers.

Last night, I noticed the frequency at which a certain task was firing was doubled; seemingly out of the blue. In order to troubleshoot I did a few things:

- cleared the redis server + celery message queues
- restarted the `celerybeat` service
- restarted the `redis-server` service

When those did not change the behavior, I tried:

- rebooting the server
- stopping the `celerybeat` service
- stopping the `redis-server` service

Even after a reboot and having all the services stopped, the task is still being triggered! I have never encountered this kind of behavior before.

How can the task continue to be triggered even without a messaging service?

Any help or troubleshooting ideas here would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: restart gunicorn service

Comment: nice suggestion but I am actually using apache2 wsgi.. I did try a restart on that service as well.